# iPad custom URL help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

So I am trying to probe the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey to see if my application was launched by another app.  For example, what if I want to do something like this:

```
if (UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey != NULL) {
    [window addSubview:launchViewController.view];
} else {
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

In other words, if the app is launched from the desktop, it will show one view, but if it called from another app through a custom URL, it will display a different view.  When I step through and examine the field, it says "Unknown type".  Any ideas?  Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use it in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I suggest using

```
 NSURL *launchURL=(NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey"];
 if (launchURL != nil) {
    [window addSubview:launchViewController.view];
} else {
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

I'm not sure but that could do the trick

Comment: Absolutely beautiful.  There are so many little quirky methods to remember to extract data like that.  Thanks a lot!